# ApplicationRoute is the best way to handle a global deserialization?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

In my project, we need to deserialize the same parameters on all the routes of our application. I'm asking if handle a deserialization in a ApplicationRoute was the best solution, or if it exist a better one ?

You can find a pseudo-example here : http://jsfiddle.net/mbreton/bff7D/

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('application', {path:"/:globalParam"}, function (){
        this.route('detail', {path:"/detail"});
    });
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function (params){
        console.log('Params contains globalParam ?', params);
        return params;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of task there are different approaches.

One approach might be to `reopen` the `Ember.Route` and place your deserialization code in the hook you provide, for example:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  model: function(params) {
    //do your task...
    this._super(params);
  }
});
```

And the other approach might be to define a super class as @sly_7 mentioned and use it as a blueprint for all your routes, like:

```
App.GeneralRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    //do your task
    return params;
  }
});

App.SomeRoute = App.GeneralRoute.extend();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after to have speak with an EmberJS contributor. The best way to handle our problem it's to wrap entirely the application with a resource. You can see a example here :
http://jsfiddle.net/mbreton/ztzyK/2/

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('global', {path:"/:globalParam"}, function (){
        this.route('index');
        this.route('detail');
    });
});

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    redirect: function (){
        this.transitionTo("global.index", {globalParam: "Youhou"});
    }
});

App.GlobalRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model){
        // only executed at the begining
        console.log('Model', model);
    }
});
```